German Criminal code: Is there a substantial explanation what makes a crime a "violent offence endangering state"?
Reading a current news item, I was stumbling (not for the first time) upon the term "staatsgefärdende Straftat" (violent offence endangering state).
The term is introduced in § 89a StGB:

(1) Wer eine schwere staatsgefährdende Gewalttat vorbereitet, wird mit Freiheitsstrafe von sechs Monaten bis zu zehn Jahren bestraft. Eine schwere staatsgefährdende Gewalttat ist eine Straftat gegen das Leben in den Fällen des § 211 oder des § 212 oder gegen die persönliche Freiheit in den Fällen des § 239a oder des § 239b, die nach den Umständen bestimmt und geeignet ist, den Bestand oder die Sicherheit eines Staates oder einer internationalen Organisation zu beeinträchtigen oder Verfassungsgrundsätze der Bundesrepublik Deutschland zu beseitigen, außer Geltung zu setzen oder zu untergraben.


(1) Whoever prepares a serious violent offence endangering the state incurs a penalty of imprisonment for a term of between six months and 10 years. A ‘serious violent offence endangering the state’ means an offence against life in the cases under section 211 [Murder] or 212 [Totschlag] or against personal liberty in the cases under section 239a [Abduction for purpose of extortion] or 239b [Hostage-taking] which, under the circumstances, is intended and suited to undermine the continued existence or security of a state or of an international organisation, or to abolish, rob of legal effect or subvert the constitutional principles of the Federal Republic of Germany.

Now I approve of specialised criminal legislation against terrorism, or more precisely against crimes that are committed to promote a political agenda. But I have a problem with understanding how the qualification of a crime that "endagers the state" is exercised.
If you take that news item as an example, it concerns a person who downloaded instructions for building pipe bombs from the internet. It seems he is charged with a crime according to § 91 (1) Nr. 2, which uses the same terminology as cited above.
But even supposing the perpretrator had been able to accomplish his goals and commit a serious terrorist act: How would he have "undermined the continued existence or security of a state" or "abolished, robed of legal effect or subverted the constitutional principles"? There have been a lot of terrorist attacks through the years, but it is hard for me to qualify most of them that way. The state may have had to take serious measures to round up the terrorists, but with the exception of the release of a group of left-wing terrorists in exchange for abducted Peter Lorenz, I do not see that it was ever pressed to act outside of its legal framework. The courts did what they were tasked with and convicted the criminals.
To me, there is a disconnect between the definition given at the end of § 89a (1) and the apparent way it is applied to criminal acts as reported in news items. And it leaves me with questions: I can imagine the "security of an organisation", but can the "security of a state" be anything else but a threat with war? To "abolish or rob of legal effect the constitutional principles" are also understandable, but what is the distinct meaning to "subvert" them?
So my question is: is there a deeper-going explanation of what qualifies a crime as "endangering the state" and how to apply the definition given at the end of § 89a (1)? For example, are there commentaries or academic texts on the matter?

Right in the text!
The qualifier for what is "staatsgefärdend" is the latter part of the paragraph:

is intended and suited to undermine the continued existence or security of a state or of an international organisation, or to abolish, rob of legal effect or subvert the constitutional principles of the Federal Republic of Germany.

This is a clear test asking basically two questions:

Is the act is intended to undermine the existence of the security of a (read: any) state, [...]?
Is the act suited to do so?

If the answer to both questions is yes, then the act is Staatsgefärdend. An example would be a coup plan that includes a bombing to kill the Bundespräsident or the Bundeskanzler or burn down the Reichstag: The provable intent would come from the manifesto of the actor, and killing these actors or destroying the meeting place is suited to achieve the subversion of the constitutional principles - such as the elections needed to get things done in certain ways.

But that is exactly where my doubt comes in. If downloading bomb-making instructions and glorifying ISIS is enough to open investigations, where is the intent and suitedness to undermine the continued existence or security of a state? What establishes a tangible relation to the quoted definition? Sorry if my question was not clear enough, I was meaning to ask whether there are further explanations to that definition, for example in legal commentaries or academic texts.

I also don't really see how killing the Bundeskanzler would really endanger the state. They just elect a new one and the order is restored. After all, he could also just die from a car crash. Several US presidents did get killed, yet the USA still exist.

Killing a specific person for a specific reason (lets say killing the Chancellor because the slept with your wife) might not be "staatsgefährdend", but killing a Chancellor for being Chancellor implies the threat that they would kill the next one for the same reason, too. And yes, threatening people by death to not participate in the democratic process of voting and getting elected is a threat to the democratic order. Just open a history book in the 1930s pages and observe how armed brownshirts in a parliament chamber can influence voting and can bring down a democracy.
